# Which application changed Mac OS X [Option]+[D] keybinding

Tags: keybindings

When I press <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> key in OS X, the current application loses focus. And if I press it again, the current window gets focus back.

How do I know which application bind that or how to avoid it. I checked the shortcuts in System Preferences and there isn't anything like <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> keybinding.

System version:

`ProductName:  Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.11.4
BuildVersion:   15E65`

This annoys me so much.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on a system running 10.11.5 Beta (15F24b), perhaps it is a bug that affects your version?

Comment: maybe not, if I create a new user, it works well.

Comment: Could you check under System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts and ensure that nothing is set to Option-D?

Comment: @perhapsmaybeharry yes, i checked that already. nothing is set to option-d

Comment: Does this happen with all applications or only a certain application?

Comment: @perhapsmaybeharry every application

Comment: @perhapsmaybeharry  Thanks for you help. Problem solved. ;-)

Comment: Which application introduced this key mapping?

Comment: @danielAzuelos  sorry, I am not sure. Because I remove several items a time. So I did not remember. ;-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a new user and login as that new user to see whether it works normally.

In my case, it works normally. Then check login items of the current user: Preferences > Users & Groups > Login items. Then remove unuseful items and relogin, remember to uncheck `reopen windows when relogin`.

Then, everything works normally. Thanks Nunzy in #MacOSX channel!

Thank you so much!!!